# How can I get donation amounts for a Contribute Page or Event via API?

Tags: civicontribute, api

**Is it possible to retrieve amounts on a contribution page via API only?**

I can retrieve the details of a CiviCRM Contribution Page via API.

```
cv api ContributionPage.get id=1
```

A missing detail I'd like in this result is the amounts which appear on the contribution page / membership form / event registration etc.

I can retrieve PriceSet and PriceField information via API, and this permits me to filter by the *type* of entity that PriceSet is associated with - but not the specific entity by ID.

```
cv api PriceSet.get extends=CiviContribute
```

In the PriceSet results, there's data available which would let me filter the results after retrieval, but I'm looking for a means to get the data by the most direct route.

I see there's a method used internally to retrieve pricesets associated with a specific contribution page entity, ex:

```
CRM_Price_BAO_PriceSet::getFor('civicrm_contribution_page', 1));
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain you are correct, I had the same challenge and arrived at the same conclusion recently (https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/issue-2840851.patch)